# Hosting .NET Core Application outside IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, hosting, kestrel

I am trying to host a `.NET Core` application with `Kestrel` not on `IIS`.And i seem getting the following error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

**MISC**

```
class Address {
        public string ProtocolType { get; set; } = "http";
        public string Host { get; set; }
        public long Port { get; set; }
        public static Address Default = new Address { Host = "localhost", Port = 9300, ProtocolType = "http" };
    }


    static class AddressExtensions {
        public static string ToUrl(this Address @this) {
            return $"{@this.ProtocolType}//{@this.Host}:{@this.Port}";
        }
    }
```

**Program**

```
public class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Start();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) {
            var builder=WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args); //crashes here !!

            builder.UseStartup("Startup");
            var url = Address.Default.ToUrl();
            builder.UseKestrel().UseUrls(url);
            return builder;

        }

    }
```

**Startup**

```
public class Startup {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
            services.AddMvcCore();

        }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) {
            app.Map("/http", x => x.UseMvc());
            app.Map("/ws", x => {

            });
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
```

Why does it try to host it on `IIS` ? I must specify that i do not have a `launchSettings.json` file. It did not create one from the `.NET Core App` template.Do i have to do it manually for running outside of `IIS`?

How can i make this server work and run outside `IIS` ?

Answer (score 1):

First, `launchSettings.json` is only for development. It is not published and not used once the app is deployed.

Second, `CreateDefaultBuilder()`, among other things, adds the IIS integration services. However, that doesn't mean that you *have* to host in IIS at that point. You certainly shouldn't be getting an error just because the IIS integration is included, but you're not hosting in IIS. If I had to hazard a guess, I'd imagine you're running a different version of the .NET Core SDK than the runtime that's installed on your server. Make sure that the two are in line with each other.

If you want to get rid of the IIS integration altogether, you'll need to stop using `CreateDefaultBuilder` and do what it does manually, minus of course the adding of the IIS integration. You can [view the source](https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/2.1.6/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/WebHost.cs) to see what the method is taking care of.

Comment: So then i can skip the `UseKestrel` ,`UseUrls`..how do i `Start` the server..etc.